# "Connection Reset" error on Django Admin file upload

Tags: python, django, apache, nginx, centos

WheneverI try to upload an mp3 file through a CMS I built with the Django Admin contrib pacakage, the server takes a couple minutes, then gives me a "Connection was reset" error.

I'm running Django on a CentOS server using NGINX which is proxying Apache with mod_wsgi for python. Could this be a server settings issue?

Comment: how did you solve this problem

Comment: i don't think i did at the time. but since then, i've discovered timeout and filesize limits in the nginx and apache confs. definitely check those.

Comment: Might be good if you've solved the issue now to post a self-answer to help others.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the max body size

If you are using NGinx, add `client_max_body_size 35m`

And if you are using Apache you have to increase this size too.